# IO thread error : 1595 (Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master)

Tags: replication, percona-server

Slave status :

```
           Last_IO_Errno: 1595
           Last_IO_Error: Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
```

from error log :

```
       [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel 'db12': Unexpected master's heartbeat data: heartbeat is not compatible with local info; the event's data: log_file_name toku10-bin.000063<D1> log_pos 97223067, Error_code: 1623
       [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel 'db12': Relay log write failure: could not queue event from master, Error_code: 1595
```

> I tried to restarting the slave_io thread for many times, still its same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to keep on start io_thread whenever it stopped manually, hope its bug from percona

I have simply written shell and scheduled the same  for every 10mins to check if io_thread is not running , start slave io_thread for channel 'db12';.   It's working as of now